# KARATE: Loop over a feature file fails when I call a feature file with scenario outline

Tags: karate

I have 2 feature files and trying to perform below operation

**FEATURE 1: [calling.feature]**

```
Feature: Test loop over by calling a feature file

Scenario Outline: Testing loop over feature file
* call read('called.feature') { argument = '<arg>' }

Examples:
|arg| 
|"HELLO"|
|"WORLD"|
```

**FEATURE 2: [called.feature]**

```
Feature: Test loop over in Karate framework

Scenario Outline: Testing loop over feature
* def callingArg = arg
* match '<arg2>' == callingArg
Examples:
|arg2| 
|"TEST1"|
|"WORLD"|
```

When I call 'Called.feature' using read in 'Calling.feature' I was expecting it will iterate using across all the examples in both feature file

but Karate exits whenever it finds the failure, in this case when parameter "HELLO" is passed from Calling.feature it fails during match step in 'called.feature' for example 'TEST1' and never tests for 'WORLD'.

***Is there a way I can force Karate to complete all the scenario examples in the called.feature???***

Below is the logs:

```
calling: [com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $, actual: 'HELLO', expected: 'TEST1', reason: not equal
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchEquals(StepDefs.java:526)
    at ✽.* match fileName == "TEST1"(called.feature:16)
, com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $, actual: 'WORLD', expected: 'TEST1', reason: not equal
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchEquals(StepDefs.java:526)
    at ✽.* match fileName == "TEST1"(called.feature:16)
, com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: feature call (loop) failed: called.feature
caller: calling.feature
items: [{mdbName=HELLO}, {mdbName=WORLD}]
errors:
-------
feature call (loop) failed at index: 0
caller: calling.feature
arg: {mdbName=HELLO}

path: $, actual: 'HELLO', expected: 'TEST1', reason: not equal
-------
feature call (loop) failed at index: 1
caller: calling.feature
arg: {mdbName=WORLD}

path: $, actual: 'WORLD', expected: 'TEST1', reason: not equal
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFeatureCall(Script.java:1636)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1579)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.callAndUpdateConfigAndAlsoVarsIfMapReturned(Script.java:1669)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.callAndUpdateConfigAndVars(StepDefs.java:571)
    at ✽.* call read('called.feature') mdbData(calling.feature:9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formatting is very hard to understand. Anyway Karate is supposed to evaluate all example rows even if there is a failure. Here is a simple example:

```
Feature:    
Scenario Outline:

* call read('called.feature') { a: <value> }    

Examples:
| value |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
```

And `called.feature` is:

```
Feature:
Scenario:

* match a == 2
```

And it works as expected. Even though rows 1 and 3 fail, all rows are executed. So you may be on an old version of Karate. Please upgrade.

EDIT: This was fixed in 0.8.0: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/421

Comment: @RakeshMahendrakar ok. the example above proves it works as expected. if you still have a problem, file a bug, and make sure you include a full working example to replicate.

Comment: I am still having issues .. will be researching more before I accept or close this question..

Comment: @RakeshMahendrakar then please delete it and create an issue when you are sure. or submit proper details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @RakeshMahendrakar closed the issue because you did not follow the instructions

Comment: Tested and worked fine on version 0.8.0  .. Thanks to you and your team for taking care of it.

Comment: @PeterThomas In my case I cannot set the value as 1,2,3. It would be dynamic like 1,2,3,4 | 1,2,3,4,5 |1,2 likewise. How to handle that

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan can't understand. ask a new question and give a proper example

Comment: In the Scenario Outline Examples, I cannot hard-code the values (as it is in the question), in the run time only I come to know the integer values.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline (note, this is just one of the ways)